# Finding death record(s) of great grandmother who emigrated from Italy in 1899?

Tags: death-records, italy

My great grandmother immigrated from Italy in 1899 because I have seen the ship's manifest.

I also know that she died soon after, but I cannot find a death certificate, any cemetery information or even the year of death.

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy StackExchange!  To get the best answer for you, it would be helpful to know which country your grand-mother immigrated to (the USA?) and where you have searched already for death records. Do you have any information that narrows down where she may have died?

Comment: Welcome, Janet!  It helps to collect all the information you have, and place life events in a timeline, with a note saying what the source is for each event.  Then you can work outward from the known events in small steps. Do you have any other records that are later in time than the passenger list?  Also, if you can tell us the form of the passenger list, that will help us get a better answer for you. What information is listed in the headers?

Comment: Are you able to provide some details such as your great grandmother's name(s) and whether she was married, please?  Without more details I am unclear who you are looking for and what is already known about her.  There is an **edit** button beneath your question that will enable you to revise it with more details.